# What datatype can I store additional time data columns in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: date, apache-iotdb, iotdb

If there are additional time columns I want to store in Apache IoTDB, can `datetime` or `datetime-input` datatype be used to store them? If I only can use `long` type in IoTDB, can `long` type data be queried for a certain time period, for example, check the data from 2023-04-01 00:00:00 to 2023-04-01 12:00:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an additional time column that needed to be store in Apache IoTDB, it is best to use `long` type, otherwise it can only be `text`. And yes, the `long` type data is able to query data for a certain time period.